# show data with selected button in datatables

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a datatables that show table from database, and this is how it's look like :
[image: datatables1]

I need to show other table when i click `button 'Detail`' and only show data that have `DEPARTMENT` name same with the `button 'Detail'` row or with the `button 'Detail'` selected.

And i've been trying this so far :

```
foreach (DataRow pRow in dtDaily.Rows)
                    {
                        string queryNew = "SELECT * FROM REPORTDATA WHERE DEPARTMENT = '"+ pRow["DEPARTMENT"] +"' ";
                        SqlCommand scNew = new SqlCommand(queryNew, con);
                        con.Open();
                        int statusNew = scNew.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        DataTable dtDailyNew = new DataTable();
                        sda.Fill(dtDailyNew);
                        rptrDETAILREPORT.DataSource = dtDailyNew;
                        rptrDETAILREPORT.DataBind();
                        con.Close();
                    }
```

but it's show all data, and this is how it's look like :

[image: datatables2]

Is it possible to show data only have `DEPARTMENT` name with selected button?

Comment: SQL Injection warning: Always use parameters.

Comment: Suggestions: (1) For two extra columns, I would just add them to the main table, and not have a button. (2) If you want the button, I would recommend using DataTable's [Child Rows](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) functionality - that might be a good fit for this requirement. Also, I would suggest not calling to the database on each button click - just fetch the data once with the main table data (but I understand that may not be what you want/need).

Comment: `int statusNew = scNew.ExecuteNonQuery();` makes no sense. `sda.Fill(dtDailyNew);`: `sda` (SQLDataAdapter) is defined in some other place and runs the same query all times, this is why you have same result for all rows.

Comment: is it possible to use datatables child rows with asp.net webforms? @andrewjames